# How to count number of files in “.tar” files inside another, nested “.tar” file without extraction?

Tags: linux, tar

There are many solutions out there on counting of files inside a `.tar` file. But I have not found a solution to count number of files in `.tar` files inside another `.tar` file without extraction.

For example:

- big.tar contains

  - a.tar
  - b.tar
  - c.sh

I can extract `big.tar` and then `tar -tvf` those `a.tar` and `b.tar` but we like to know if there’s a better solution on Linux?

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is no.

The proper way would be something like

```
$ tar -t -f <(tar -x -O -f big.tar a.tar) | wc -l
```

or

```
$ tar -x -O -f big.tar a.tar | tar -t -f - | wc -l
```

This will extract `a.tar` from `big.tar`, and feed that directly to another `tar` process without extracting to a file first.  Note that it is still extracting `a.tar`, just not writing to disk.

It is possible to extract through multiple layers of `tar` in one go, but you would have to write a program to do this, as I don't think anyone has written one already, and it wouldn't be a trivial undertaking.

Edit: You can modify the above shell script if you want to count the files in ALL sub-tarballs:

```
tar -t -f big.tar | egrep '\.tar$' | while read f
do
    tar -t -f <(tar -x -0 -f big.tar "$f")
done | wc -l
```

Or with GNU Parallel:

```
tar -t -f big.tar | egrep '\.tar$' | parallel "tar -t -f <(tar -x -0 -f big.tar {})" | wc -l
```